# How does a neural network get its output?

Tags: neural-networks

I want to create my own neural network but I'm not grasping the concept of how the neural network gets trained/gets to an output.

Say you have the following example: [link to example](http://progur.com/2016/09/how-to-create-and-use-neural-networks-in-javascript.html)

As you can see in the `var trainingdata` there is exact data on what you want the neural network (hamster) to output.

If the machine finishes training that data, why is it that if you input:

`[0, 1]`

it returns:

`Sit Neuron: 0.014995911436294706%
Run Neuron: 99.39201708556335%
Jump Neuron: 1.2615268528823826%`

To my understanding it should return the following:

`Sit Neuron: 0%
Run Neuron: 100%
Jump Neuron: 0%`

Because the machine can literally compare the input `[0, 1]` with the trainingdata, which contains the exact output.

Why is it that the machine still considers the jump and sit to be valid?

Comment: Questions specific to how Javascript works is off topic here.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I may say this question is on topic but almost impossible to answer.

Comment: It is hard to answer since too much background information is needed. It is not a popular library / software implementation, and not a popular data set. The question is not general for other people's interest.

Comment: As you can see from the link this is done using Javascript. So I interpreted "the machine still considers the jump an sit to be valid" to refer to what the code is doing rather than something that is a property of a neural network.

Answer (score 0):

Because a neural network is not perfect. First of all, it will always 'approach' the goal through the gradient. Second of all, your network will squash the values it receives with an **activation function**. If that is sigmoid function, it will never hit 1 (in your case, 100%). It always approaches 1.

You also have to take the learning rate into account.